# SQLite Bracket "don't work"

Tags: sql, sqlite

In SQLite version 3.7.12.1 (console) this query does not work:

```
(SELECT * FROM A
UNION
SELECT * FROM B)
EXCEPT
(SELECT * FROM A
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM B);
```

Error message

> Error: near line 1: near "(": syntax error

This query works in SQL Server Management Studio. Other queries with brackets do work as expected. Am I missing something?

Edit: to clarify:

```
SELECT * FROM A;     <-- works
(SELECT * FROM A);   <-- does not work [Error: near line 1: near "(": syntax error]
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.id IN (SELECT B.id FROM B);   <-- works, so no fundamental issues with brackets and sqlite...
```

Comment: about **Edit** examples: it is correct behavior according to `ANSI SQL`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems like SQLite doesn't like combined (sub)queries (those with `UNION`, `UNION ALL`, `EXCEPT` or `INTERSECT`) to be bracketed:

- this **doesn't** work:

  ```
  (SELECT 1 AS v
  UNION
  SELECT 2)
  EXCEPT
  SELECT 1
  ```
- this **doesn't** work either:

  ```
  SELECT 1 AS v
  UNION
  (SELECT 2
  EXCEPT
  SELECT 1)
  ```

(But [both](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/12066) [work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/12068) in SQL Server.)

And without brackets, the individual subselects are combined sequentially, i.e. there's no inherent priority to any of the operators like in some other SQL products. (For instance, this

```
SELECT 1 AS v
UNION
SELECT 2
INTERSECT
SELECT 3
```

[returns `1`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/12071) in SQL Server (because `INTERSECT` is performed first) and [nothing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9eecb7/5966) in SQLite.)

The only workaround seems to be to use the parts you want to combine, as subqueries, [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/a1c03/1):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM A
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM B
)
EXCEPT
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM A
  INTERSECT
  SELECT * FROM B
)
```

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @chrismarx: Not sure what exactly you are asking about, but if it's about precedence rules of set operators in SQL Server, I've managed to find something in [this manual page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks).

Comment: Hi, I can clarify, I was asking about documentation about this specific behavior (not allowing braces around a select in conjunction with a union) in Sqlite, this behavior caught me by surprise when I testing queries across Postgres and Sqlite

Comment: @chrismarx: Oh I see, sorry. No, I haven't seen any official documentation about brackets around queries or around UNION/EXCEPT/INTERSECT legs in SQLite. Whatever I'm stating in this answer regarding SQLite I've discovered empirically only.

Answer (score 0):

```
((SELECT * FROM A)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM B))
EXCEPT
((SELECT * FROM A)
INTERSECT
(SELECT * FROM B));
```

Comment: does not work, I have edited my original question to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Provide information as to why this would work. Not just a code snippet.