# Is it possible to EXCEPT two unioned selects?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got two unioned select statements like this

```
SELECT value1 FROM table1 WHERE value2 = 'the'
UNION
SELECT value1 FROM table1 WHERE value2 = 'quick'
```

Then another two unioned select statements like this

```
SELECT value1 FROM table1 WHERE value2 = 'brown'
UNION
SELECT value1 FROM table1 WHERE value2 = 'fox'
```

I'd like to combine the results of these two queries using EXCEPT. Is this possible? How would I do it?  If at all possible, I'd prefer to avoid temp tables or other complexities.

I've tried simply sticking EXCEPT in between the two groups, but that obviously didn't work. Then I tried Putting each group in parenthesis, and adding EXCEPT between them.

I know it may seem basic to some folks, but I don't do much SQL, so it's not as obvious to me.

If it makes any difference, I'm using SQLite.

Comment: What have you tried?  This isn't so hard -- assuming your database uses `EXCEPT` -- so it would be helpful to see your attempt.

Comment: @jarlh Where would I put the parentheses?

Comment: @GordonLinoff If this isn't so hard, would you mind explaining it to me?

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove the results from the two last queries from the overall result, so you can use EXCEPT with both of them; in other words, (A + B) − (C + D) = A + B − C − D:

```
SELECT value1 FROM table1 WHERE value2 = 'the'
UNION
SELECT value1 FROM table1 WHERE value2 = 'quick'
EXCEPT
SELECT value1 FROM table1 WHERE value2 = 'brown'
EXCEPT
SELECT value1 FROM table1 WHERE value2 = 'fox'
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently this is not as straightforward in SQLite, which is why I was having trouble.

Instead of doing this...

```
(SELECT value1 FROM table1 WHERE value2 = 'the'
UNION
SELECT value1 FROM table1 WHERE value2 = 'quick')

EXCEPT

(SELECT value1 FROM table1 WHERE value2 = 'brown'
UNION
SELECT value1 FROM table1 WHERE value2 = 'fox')
```

Whick works in SQL server and other places, you have to do this...

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT value1 FROM table1 WHERE value2 = 'the'
UNION
SELECT value1 FROM table1 WHERE value2 = 'quick')

EXCEPT

SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT value1 FROM table1 WHERE value2 = 'brown'
UNION
SELECT value1 FROM table1 WHERE value2 = 'fox')
```

Thank you [Andriy M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297408/andriy-m), for providing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10828913/38695). Which explained that parenthesis don't work the same in SQLite, and provided a workaround.